# Possibly not an acceptable proof for uncountablity of countable product of countable sets

Tags: general-topology, alternative-proof

Here is a text from the book *Topology* by Munkres:

> **Theorem 7.7.** $ \ \ \ $ *Let $X$ denote the two element set $\{0,1\}.$ Then the set $X^\omega$ is uncountable.*
>
> *Proof.* $\ \ \ \ $ We show that, given any function $$g:\mathbb{Z}_+\longrightarrow X^\omega,$$ $g$ is not surjective. For this purpose, let us denote $g(n)$ as follows: $$g(n)=(x_{n1},x_{n2},x_{n3},..,x_{nn},...),$$ where each $x_{ij}$ is either $0$ or $1$. Then we define an element ${\bf y}=(y_1,y_2,...,y_n,...)$ of $X^\omega$ by letting $$y_n=\begin{cases}0 &\text{if }x_{nn}=1, \\ 1 &\text{if }x_{nn}=0. \end{cases}$$ (If we write the numbers $x_{ni}$ in a rectangular array, the particular elements $x_{nn}$ appear as the diagonal entries in this array; we choose $\bf y$ so that its $n$th coordinate *differs* from the diagonal entry $x_{nn}$.)
>
> Now $\bf y$ is an element of $X^\omega$, and $\bf y$ does not lie in the image of $g$; given $n$, the point $g(n)$ and the point $\bf y$ differ in at least one coordinate, namely, the $n$th. Thus, $g$ is not surjective. $$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

I understand the text but I don't think that the argument is correct to be considered as proof. After choosing some arbitrary sequence of $0$'s and $1$'s (say $\alpha$), we fix it before defining $y$; i.e. $y$ is defined based on a fixed element of $g(n)$, i.e. $\alpha$, so

$1$ - How to prove that if $y\ne \alpha$ then $y\notin g(n)$ ? [note that $y$ is not a fixed unique entity]

$2$ - (Clarifications about the the mentioned proof and/or) A simpler more clear alternative proof much be appreciated.

---

Easier but similar example : Let $Y={\{1,2,3}\}$ and $Z={\{a_1,a_2,a_3}\}$ and suppose that I want to show that given any function $f: Y\rightarrow Z$, $f$ is not surjective. Let us define $f(i)=a_i$. Choose one of $a_i$'s arbitrarily and define $z=a_{i+1}$ (mod $\mathbb {Z_3}$). Since $y=a_{i+1}\ne a_i$, and $a_i$ was chosen arbitrarily so $y$ is not the image of $f$ so $f$ is not surjective. Same absurdness is going on the mentioned text from the book.

Comment: Are you sure $y$ is not fixed?

Comment: *After choosing some arbitrary sequence of* $0$'s *and* $1$'*s (say* $\alpha$*), we fix it before defining* $y$; *i.e*. $y$ *is defined based on a fixed element of* $g(n)$, *i.e*. $\alpha$ --- The proof does not involve picking an arbitrary sequence of $0$'s and $1$'s, but rather an arbitrary SEQUENCE of such sequences. The picking is of the function $g,$ and this means that $g(1)$ is defined (which will be a sequence of $0$'s and $1$'s) and $g(2)$ is defined  (which will be a sequence of $0$'s and $1$'s) and $g(3)$ is defined  (which will be a sequence of $0$'s and $1$'s) and $g(4) \ldots$

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro - Even if the chosen sequence is an arbitrary one, why defined $g(n)$ is any possible function to be defined for $\mathbb{Z}^+ \to X^\omega$?

Comment: The statement to be proved reduces to showing that any chosen $g$ fails to be surjective. This is done by picking an arbitrary $g$ and then showing that $g$ (the function picked) is not surjective. For example, suppose I wanted to show that every book on your bookshelf has less than 400000 pages. One way to do this is to prove that no matter which book I select from your bookshelf, the book selected will have less than 400000 pages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The argument is fine and is arguably the simplest possible argument; you’ve simply misunderstood it. I have no idea what your $\alpha$ is. The element $y$ of $X^\omega$ is *not* defined from some particular sequence of zeroes and ones; it depends only on the function $g$, and once $g$ has been given, $y$ is fixed.

The idea of the proof is very simple. It gives an algorithm for taking *any* function $g:\Bbb Z_+\to X^\omega$ and constructing from $g$ an element $y^{(g)}=\langle y_1^{(g)},y_2^{(g)},y_3^{(g)},\ldots\rangle$ of $X^\omega$ in such a way that $y^{(g)}$ is not in the range of $g$. This shows that there is no surjection from $\Bbb Z_+$ to $X^\omega$ and hence certainly no bijection.

How do we make sure that $y^{(g)}\ne g(n)$ for any $n\in\omega$? We simply make sure to define $y^{(g)}$ so that it differs from $g(n)$ in the $n$-th position. If $g(n)$ has a $0$ in the $n$-th position (i.e., if $x_{nn}=0$), then we make sure that $y_n^{(g)}=1$ instead, and if $g(n)$ has a $1$ in the $n$-th position (i.e., if $x_{nn}=1$), then we make sure that $y_n^{(g)}=0$ instead.

Imagine arranging the sequences $g(1),g(2),g(3),\ldots$ in a column, like this:

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
\color{red}{x_{11}}&x_{12}&x_{13}&x_{14}&x_{15}&\ldots\\
x_{21}&\color{red}{x_{22}}&x_{23}&x_{24}&x_{25}&\ldots\\
x_{31}&x_{32}&\color{red}{x_{33}}&x_{34}&x_{35}&\ldots\\
x_{41}&x_{42}&x_{43}&\color{red}{x_{44}}&x_{45}&\ldots\\
x_{51}&x_{52}&x_{53}&x_{54}&\color{red}{x_{55}}&\ldots\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&
\end{array}$$

This array is completely determined by the function $g$ that we’re given. Now we look at the diagonal sequence of zeroes and ones, which I’ve marked in red:

$$x_{11},x_{22},x_{33},x_{44},x_{55},\ldots\tag{1}$$

This is a sequence of zeroes and ones that is determined by the function $g$. We create a new sequence $y^{(g)}$ (Munkres’ $y$, but I’m emphasizing its dependence on $g$) by changing each $0$ in the sequence $(1)$ to a $1$ and each $1$ to a $0$. Can this sequence

$$y_1^{(g)},y_2^{(g)},y_3^{(g)},y_4^{(g)},y_5^{(g)},\ldots$$

be equal to any row of the array? No: it differs from row $3$, for instance, which is the sequence $g(3)$, in the $3$-rd position: $g(3)$ has $x_{33}$ there, and $y_3^{(g)}$ is whichever of $0$ and $1$ is ***not*** $x_{33}$. The same goes for each row of the array, i.e., for each of the sequences $g(n)$, so the sequence $y^{(g)}$ is not equal to $g(n)$ for any $n\in\Bbb Z_+$. It’s an element of $X^\omega$ that is not in the range of $g$, so $g$ cannot be surjective. And since this algorithm works no matter what function $g$ we start with, no function $g:\Bbb Z_+\to X\to\omega$ can be surjective.

Comment: The problem is that you can add $y$ to the list of $g(n)$, even if in $g(n)$, $n$ is infinity you add any number to countable infinite and still is countable infinite. Suppose that after $g(n)$ is defined I shift all the $n$'s by one and name $y$ as $g(1)$.

Comment: @Liebe You are basically saying, "OK, so you proved my $g(n)$ is no good, but here's a new function which I will also call $g(n)$, and it patches up the hole you found." You could go on like this forever, because there will _always_ be a "hole" in any function you construct, but there is always another function that doesn't have a hole in the same place. And yes, you _are_ substituting a new function for the old one each time--you can't change any of the outputs of a function and claim it's still the same function.

Comment: @Liebe: No, you cannot. First, $n$ cannot be ‘infinity’: the domain of $g$ is $\Bbb Z_+$, whose elements are the ordinary positive integers. You can define a new function $g'$, say, by setting $g'(1)=y$ and $g'(n)=g(n-1)$ for $n>1$, and this function will have $y$ in its range, but so what? The same algorithm will produce a new sequence $y'$ that is not in the range of $g'$.

Comment: What do you mean by "adding y to the list" ? $g$ is fixed, so so is its range.  You work from there...

Comment: @Liebe: Instead of trying to repair your argument, which is fatally flawed, you should concentrate on trying to understand the correct one. Once again, the key idea is that no matter what function $g$ you try, this algorithm produces a sequence of zeroes and ones that is not in the range of $g$. Yes, you can change $g$, but the algorithm will then produce a different sequence, one that is not in the range of the changed function.

Comment: @Liebe: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 3):

For your reference, this is the classical proof of the theorem. The argument is called Cantor's Diagonalization Argument.

$y$ is not based on a fixed element of $g(n)$, it is made from all the values $g$ may take.

Here is how it is constructed in more detail. We choose some arbitrary, but fixed, function $g:\mathbb{Z}^+ \to X^\omega$. For our example we will let $g(1)=\{1,1,0,1,...\}$, $g(2)=\{1,0,1,0,...\}$, $g(3)=\{0,0,0,0,...\}.$

Now we construct $y$. Since the first element of the sequence of $g(1)$ is $1$, we make $y_1$ the opposite, that is $y_1=0$. Now the *second* element of $g(2)$ is $0$, so $y_2=1$. Now the third element of $g(3)$ is $0$, so $y_3=1$. The process continues for defining all the elements of $y$.

Now we compare $y = \{0,1,1,...\}$ with $g(n)$. By the way it was constructed we see that $y\neq g(1)$, $y\neq g(2)$, $y \neq g(3)$, and so forth.

Thus $g$ misses a sequence contained in $X^\omega$. Such a sequence can be constructed for any such function $g$. If $g$ didn't miss a sequence, then $g$ would be surjective and $X^\omega$ would be countable. Conversely, if $X^\omega$ was countable, there must be some function $g : \mathbb{Z}^+ \to X^\omega$ such that $g$ is surjective.

We have just shown that any such function $g$ cannot be surjective, thus $X^\omega$ is not countable.

Comment: What is the problem? For $any$ map $g:\mathbb{Z}^+ \to X^\omega$, the range is countable and so we may list it $g(1), g(2), ...$ etc. Then, the diagonalization argument goes through fine. That is, we form a sequence that is not among $any$ of the $g(n)$, which proves that $g$ is not onto.