# Is ${\{1\}}^\omega$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_+$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

[Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1709302/possibly-not-an-acceptable-proof-for-uncountablity-of-countable-product-of-count) is a proof that countably infinite product of countable sets is not (always/never?) countable.

My question is : what if $X={\{1\}}$ ? i.e. Is $g:\mathbb{Z}_+\to X^\omega$ surjective (or even maybe bijective)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\{1\}^{\omega}$ is a set with one element, namely the function that returns $1$ for every argument in $\omega$. Therefore every function $\mathbb Z_+\to\{1\}^\omega$ is surjective, but it can't be injective.

More precisely, with the usual representation of functions, $\{1\}^{\omega}$ is exactly the set whose only element is the Cardesian product $\omega\times\{1\}$, or in other words,
$$ \{1\}^\omega = \bigl\{\{(0,1),(1,1),(2,1),(3,1),\ldots\}\bigr\}$$

The theorem that $X^\omega$ is uncountable depends on an assumption that $X$ has at least two different elements.

There is no $X$ such that $X^\omega$ is countably infinite.

Comment: @Edi: For this purpose I'm assuming that $A^B$ means the set of all functions $B\to A$. If you want instead to work in a setting where $\{1\}^\omega$ is a set of infinite sequences, it will still be a set of exactly one element -- and that element is the sequence $(1,1,1,1,\ldots)$. (How exactly that sequence is represented in set theory varies, but the function $\omega\to\{1\}$ I've written is actually a common choice for it).

Comment: @Edi: I say that because there is no $X$ such that $X^\omega$ is countably infinite. It appears that you think that $\{1\}^\omega$ is countably infinite, but it is not inifinite at all. It has **one** element; one is a finite number.